# Instabilities in the CDMT

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy

Could anyone explain or refer to references on why the CDMT f(R) gravity model suffers from Instabilities any why the sign of ${\mu}^{4}$ matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metric $f(R)$ Instability](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105230/metric-fr-instability)